# AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, audioqueue

My calls to AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer are failing, with OSStatus -66686. I've never seen this error code before, and am able to find no information on it anywhere. Converting it to an NSError and printing its description gives me the following console output:

Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-66686 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -66686.)"

Here's all my relevant AudioQueue initialization code:

```
AudioQueueRef       audioQueue;
AudioQueueBufferRef aq_buffer[3];
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
streamFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
streamFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
streamFormat.mReserved = 0;

OSStatus err;
err = AudioQueueNewOutput(&streamFormat, AudioPlayCallback, self, 
                          CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &audioQueue);

// Start playback
err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);

// Enqueue buffers
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    err = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer (audioQueue, 1024, &aq_buffer[i]); 
    err = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (audioQueue, aq_buffer[i], 0, NULL);
    NSLog(@"err : %d", err);
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain
                                         code:err
                                         userInfo:nil];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}
```

I've tried modifying the size of the buffer I allocate, which has no effect (and the call to AudioQueueAllocateBuffer does not fail anyway). I've tried switching the order of calls between AudioQueueStart and the buffer allocation and enqueueing calls, to no effect. I've checked the comments in AudioQueue.h, and I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong. The error description is too vague to be helpful.

Why is my AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer call failing?

Answer (score 5):

A search with Spotlight reveals that *"66686"* is to be found in `AudioQueue.h`:

```
kAudioQueueErr_BufferEmpty          = -66686
```

So, whatever you are trying to do, the buffer is empty.

From a quick look at the code above, it looks to me like the SpeakHere recording code. However, you've set it up above for playback.

In either case, you need to allocate the queue's buffers before starting the queue. For recording, your function callback will be invoked periodically when newly recorded data is available.

For playback, the function callback will be invoked periodically when you need to supply more audio data to the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Even after allocating the buffers, you'll have to populate the buffers with data. In the case of playing from a file, I suspect AudioFileReadPackets does it for you. But if you are e.g. playing from a stream, you'll have to push the data into the buffer yourself.

This worked for me:

```
char pcmData[pcmDataSize];

// add your own code here to populate pcmData with the PCM data to playback

memcpy(audioQueueBufferRef->mAudioData,pcmData, pcmDataSize);
audioQueueBufferRef->mAudioDataByteSize = pcmDataSize;
audioQueueBufferRef->mPacketDescriptionCount = pcmDataSize/2; // change this according to your num bytes per frame
AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(audioQueueRef, audioQueueBufferRef, 0, NULL);
```

AudioQueueAllocateBuffer was done in an earlier preparation step.

Comment: I'have the same error ?
How I can play silence with audioqueue, because AudioQueue seem failed when the decoder not match with the data in the buffer ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that when you are recording that you use "AudioQueueNewInput", and not "AudioQueueNewOutput".  I copied and pasted some code and it took me a while to see this minor difference.  If you make this mistake you will get the "kAudioQueueErr_BufferEmpty" (-66686) error each time you call "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer".